# In $(X,d)$ metric space, an intersection of finite families of open sets is open.

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone help prove this? I am allowed to used the fact that $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open and that a union of an arbitrary family of open sets is open.

I tried to understand what it says in my textbook, but it makes no sense to me. It goes like this:

If the sets $U_1, U_2,...,U_k$ are open and $x$ is a point which lays in their intersection, then there exist a finite number of balls $B_{r_1}(x),..,B_{r_k}(x)$ such that $B(x,r_i)\subset U_i$. The ball $B(x,r)$ with the radius $r=\min\{r_1,..r_k\}$ lays in $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}U_i$

Comment: Please could you give us some indication of what you've tried.

Comment: Since you are in a metric space, it should be fairly straightforward if you draw a picture. Try drawing blobs that overlap at some point, then define an open ball for points in the intersection of the blobs. It will give you a good idea as to how you would prove it.

Comment: What is your definition of open set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for editing your question with an explanation of the problem you're having.  You didn't understand the paragraph

> If the sets $U_1, U_2,...,U_k$ are open and $x$ is a point which lays in their intersection, then there exist a finite number of balls $B_{r_1}(x),..,B_{r_k}(x)$ such that $B(x,r_i)\subset U_i$. The ball $B(x,r)$ with the radius $r=\min\{r_1,..r_k\}$ lays in $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}U_i$

Let's go through this step by step.

> If the sets $U_1, U_2,...,U_k$ are open

Routine step.  We want to show that the intersection of finitely many open sets is open, so we start by fixing a finite collection of open sets.

> and $x$ is a point which lays in their intersection

What's the definition of an open set?  Why, it's a set $U$ such that for each point $x\in U$ there exists some $r>0$ such that $B(x, r)\subset U$.  If $U=\bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$, then we want to show that $U$ is open.  So we fix a point $x$ in $U$ and try to find some open ball $B(x, r)$ around $x$ that's contained inside this intersection $U$.

> then there exist a finite number of balls $B_{r_1}(x),..,B_{r_k}(x)$ such that $B(x,r_i)\subset U_i$

Now we need to use the fact that $U_1,\dots U_k$ are open.  This means that for each $i=1,\dots k$, and for each $y\in U_i$ there is $s$ such that $B(y, s)\subset U_i$.  What's the most obvious way to apply this?  Why, by taking $y=x$, of course - since $x$ is contained in the intersection of the $U_i$, it must be contained in each $U_i$ individually. So for each $i=1,\dots k$ there must be some $r_i$ such that $B(x, r_i)\subset U_i$.  Note that $r_i$ could take a different value for each $i$.

> The ball $B(x,r)$ with the radius $r=\min\{r_1,..r_k\}$ lays in $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}U_i$

This is the only slightly clever bit.  We've got our $r_i$ such that $B(x, r_i)\subset U_i$, but we want some $r$ such that $B(x, r)\subset\bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$ (in order to show that $\bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$ is open).  What value of $r$ can we take?  It turns out that we can take $r=\min\{r_1,\dots,r_k\}$.

**Exercise:** show that if $r=\min\{r_1,\dots,r_k\}$ then $B(x, r)\subset\bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$.

This is not completely trivial, but should still be doable.  Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch for all this detail, very much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a finite family $(U_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ of open subsets. You need to prove that $$U =\displaystyle \bigcap\limits_{1 \le i \le n} U_i$$ is a neighborhood of all its point.

So pickup $x \in U$. For $1 \le i \le n$, $x$ is in $U_i$ wich is open. So one can find $r_i >0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r_i)$ centered on $x$ of radius $r_i$ is included in $U_i$. Then take $$r =\min\limits_{1 \le i \le n} r_i$$ $r$ is stricly positive as we take the minimum of a finite set of stricly positive numbers. Also $B(x,r) \subset U$ which concludes the proof.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting this; see my comment on Giant Tortoise's answer for an explanation why.

Comment: Your profile description is very accurate.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Don't worry, it's entirely OP's loss. Won't learn, and thus will just keep on coming back, feeding ego-driven people SE points.